# Saving state of custom object ArrayList

Tags: android

I would like to restore the state of my array after a change of orientation. But I don't see an aproprieted function for this case. What shoul I do?

```
public class PuzzlePiece extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    public int xCoord;
    public int yCoord;
    public int pieceWidth;
    public int pieceHeight;
    public boolean canMove = true;

    public PuzzlePiece(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
```

This is my onSave method

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);    
        outState.putParcelableArray("image", pieces);
    }
}
```

And data initalization:

```
ArrayList<PuzzlePiece> pieces;
```

Comment: Are the ImageViews in the ArrayList always part of the Activity's layout? Or do you keep them around to add and remove them if necessary?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'm not sure to be honest, I'm following tutorial which is available here.

Answer (score -1):

Basically speaking, you need to implement two methods: saveData() and loadData(). These will use GSON library in order to transform any object into a string and then re-create them back. Then you save and restore your objects where ever you need. You may do so when onPause() method is called, or anywhere else.

Here is the code:

Firstly, add the following dependency line in your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Then you write those two methods

```
 private void saveData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences id", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(arraylistOfYourObjects);
    editor.putString("data_id", json);
    editor.apply();
}

private void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences id", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("data_id", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourObjectClass>>() {}.getType();
    arraylistOfYourObjects = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    if(arraylistOfYourObjects == null){
        arraylistOfYourObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Here is a link to a complete video on how to do the whole thing with allthe details:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcliHGR3CHo

Comment: I would say this approach is quite outdated. Using a `ViewModel` would achieve the same result with near to no boilerplate.

Comment: Could you please share a link how to do that?

Comment: You can just search for most of the Android documentation, but here's a link anyway: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: As far as I could notice, ViewModel doesn't let the data to survive after you quit the app. Whereas saving in SharedPreferences survives whatever, including quitting the app, which may be needed in many cases.

Comment: Yes you're right, but the question was about persisting on orientation, so this would be overkill for that.